# Reading PCACLIENT memory from explorer.exe

Tags: c++, string, memory

I'm making an application in C++ to list all the applications the user has launched in the past few hours. One of the methods I'm trying to implement is using memory in explorer which lists the recently executed executables.

For example, in Process Hacker, I would simply go into explorer's memory and search for pcaclient, double click on the first result and I have my data.

Here's my code for the C++ version (using this built in code brackets function didn't work properly:

https://hastebin.com/pukojobika.cpp

However, when I restart explorer, the memory address changes every time. (in the case of the code above, `0x127d02d0`. How would I go about searching for the PCACLIENT string in the memory and making sure that the resulting memory address contains data longer than 16 characters long?

Thanks.

Comment: What you're seeing is Address Space Layout Randomization, an intentional anti-hacking technique. Since your code is using similar techniques (not following API's), you're facing similar problems. IOW: **this is intentional**.

Comment: So how would I go about making my code work? Obviously it's possible to search for the string PCACLIENT in PH2 and get the memory address from there, so it must be possible in c++.

Comment: Could someone show me how to find the memory address of TRACE,0000 by searching for that string in explorer.exe and finding the address? Preferably using the above code to read the memory, but not required.